# Renouncing property and wealth

Tags: pali-canon, rebirth, belief, parents, awareness

My question is about supreme peace that is received from renunciation.

When people renounce a major portion of their possession and title, they are believed to get supreme peace.

Where I can get a detailed discussion about renunciation and a little logical discussion too that makes a person renounce?

```
 The ASIAN continent is filled with Buddhist, and Muslim countries. Many users of Buddhist countries can sufficiently address my concern. my concern is the risk associated with renunciation.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Renunciation in Buddhism is related to going forth from the lay or householder life to life as a monk or nun.

It doesn't apply to lay people renouncing property or inheritance.

In fact, lay people are advised to manage their finances well.

There is good discussion in [this article](http://www.urbandharma.org/udharma5/buddhisteco.html), [this article](http://www.urbandharma.org/udharma5/ecostability.html) and [this article](http://wisdomquarterly.blogspot.com/2010/08/4-steps-to-buddhist-money-management.html). You can read those for much advice.

For canonical advice:

The [Sigalovada Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.31.0.ksw0.html) states:

> The wise endowed with virtue Shine forth like a burning fire,
> Gathering wealth as bees do honey And heaping it up like an ant hill.
> Once wealth is accumulated, Family and household life may follow. By
> dividing wealth into four parts, True friendships are bound; One part
> should be enjoyed; Two parts invested in business; And the fourth set
> aside Against future misfortunes."

The [Dighajanu Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an08/an08.054.than.html) states:

> "And what does it mean to maintain one's livelihood in tune? There is
> the case where a lay person, knowing the income and outflow of his
> wealth, maintains a livelihood in tune, neither a spendthrift nor a
> penny-pincher, [thinking], 'Thus will my income exceed my outflow, and
> my outflow will not exceed my income.' Just as when a weigher or his
> apprentice, when holding the scales, knows, 'It has tipped down so
> much or has tipped up so much,' in the same way, the lay person,
> knowing the income and outflow of his wealth, maintains a livelihood
> in tune, neither a spendthrift nor a penny-pincher, [thinking], 'Thus
> will my income exceed my outflow, and my outflow will not exceed my
> income.'
>
> "These are the four drains on one's store of wealth: debauchery in
> sex; debauchery in drink; debauchery in gambling; and evil friendship,
> evil companionship, evil camaraderie. Just as if there were a great
> reservoir with four inlets and four drains, and a man were to close
> the inlets and open the drains, and the sky were not to pour down
> proper showers, the depletion of that great reservoir could be
> expected, not its increase.

The [Adiya Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an05/an05.041.than.html) discusses the 5 benefits obtained from one's wealth. The fifth is charity.

And don't forget that income should come from Right Livelihood, as stated in the [Vanijja Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an05/an05.177.than.html):

> "Monks, a lay follower should not engage in five types of business.
> Which five? Business in weapons, business in human beings, business in
> meat, business in intoxicants, and business in poison.

Comment: excellent answer (at least the few sentences i read)